# Mapping multiple hibernate Entities inside non-entity java bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi I am using a spring boot app with Hibernate using Oracle as DB.

I have 5 classes named

1.Reqest -> Mapped with Request Table

2.Team -> Mapped with Team Table

3.Partner -Mapped with Partner Table

4.Customer -> Mapped with Customer Table

Now I want to Display a Summary of Request on summary screen of the app where all the information from above-mentioned tables is needed.

Suppose I create a bean class as follows.

```html
public class SummaryBean{
 
 Request req;
 
 Team team;
 
 Customer cust;
 
 Partner part;
 
 
 //Getter setters;
 
 




}
```

Now since I have all the tables mapped with Java classes I can use hql join query to fetch data.

I don't want use plain SQL query with join and then iterate the resulting Object[] list from hibernate query and stub data into SummaryBean manually.

All the above-mentioned tables have REQ_ID as joining column

My question is How can I make hibernate map the result of that query to SummaryBean object?
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use constructor query.

Something like

```
"select new SummaryBean(req, team, cust, part) from (here you join your tables)"
```

You need to provide a constructor for the SummaryBean with those 4 types.

Note that the SummaryBean class doesn't have to be mapped, but you might have to use fully qualified name in the query (packageName.className).

Comment: absolutely spot on man!! Yes I had to use fully qualified name for SummaryBean

Comment: Glad I could help. I was working with the same this week :)